How to debug dart pkg kernel lib?
I encountered some problems with src/third_party/dart/pkg/kernel/lib/library_index.dart in Flutter engine when I ran flutter build --verbose. There is an exception when running the dartaotruntime command
#0      _MemberTable.getMember (package:kernel/library_index.dart:391)
#1      _MemberTable.getField (package:kernel/library_index.dart:415)
#2      _ContainerTable.getField (package:kernel/library_index.dart:229)
#3      LibraryIndex.getField (package:kernel/library_index.dart:127)
#4      new FfiTransformer.<anonymous closure> (package:vm/modular/transformations/ffi/common.dart:555)
#5      MapBase.map (dart:collection/maps.dart:82)
#6      new FfiTransformer (package:vm/modular/transformations/ffi/common.dart:554)
#7      new _FfiDefinitionTransformer (package:vm/modular/transformations/ffi/definitions.dart:128)
#8      transformLibraries (package:vm/modular/transformations/ffi/definitions.dart:89)
#9      VmTarget.performModularTransformationsOnLibraries (package:vm/modular/target/vm.dart:170)
#10     KernelTarget.runBuildTransformations (package:front_end/src/fasta/kernel/kernel_target.dart:1590)
#11     KernelTarget.buildComponent.<anonymous closure> (package:front_end/src/fasta/kernel/kernel_target.dart:648)
<asynchronous suspension>
#12     withCrashReporting (package:front_end/src/fasta/crash.dart:133)

I am wondering how to debug the Dart compiler framework itself?
How can I add breakpoints with devtools to debug dartaotruntime command?
